# More concise jq code to get each value from file and place in another

Tags: json, bash, jq

My goal is to get each value of a group of keypairs, and insert each into another file. I could do this line by line, but is there a cleaner way to add them all at once?

I have the result of an aws query which gives me the following file called `vpc.json` (with sensitive info stripped);

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Client VpcId", 
        "OutputKey": "VpcId", 
        "OutputValue": "vpc-a12345"
    }, 
    {
        "OutputKey": "ServiceSubnet1", 
        "OutputValue": "subnet-b12345"
    }, 
    {
        "OutputKey": "PublicSubnet1", 
        "OutputValue": "subnet-c12345"
    }, 
    {
        "OutputKey": "ServiceSubnet0", 
        "OutputValue": "subnet-d12345"
    }, 
    {
        "OutputKey": "PublicSubnet0", 
        "OutputValue": "subnet-e12345"
    }
]
```

And I'd like each value to end up in `parameters.json`, which already has a bunch of other keypairs, with the final file looking like;

```
[
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "VpcId",
    "ParameterValue": "vpc-a12345"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "ServiceSubnet0",
    "ParameterValue": "subnet-b12345"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "ServiceSubnet1",
    "ParameterValue": "subnet-c12345"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "PublicSubnet0",
    "ParameterValue": "subnet-d12345"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "PublicSubnet1",
    "ParameterValue": "subnet-e12345"
  }
]
```

Right now I can "easily" achieve this with the following code. This would be the snippet required just for the `VpcId` pair, meaning I would have to duplicate it x5, one for each keypair.

The code checks to see if the keypair already exists, adding it if not (necessary because this needs to be backwards compatible with older files). It then gets the relevant value from the vpc file and places it in the parameters file.

```
if ! grep -q "VpcId" parameters.json
    then
        jq --argjson obj '{ "ParameterKey": "VpcId", "ParameterValue": "" }' '. += [$obj]' <parameters.json | sponge parameters.json
fi

keyVpc=$(jq -r '.[] | select(.OutputKey=="VpcId") | .OutputValue' < vpc.json)

jq --arg keyVpc "$keyVpc" '(.[] | select(.ParameterKey == "VpcId") | .ParameterValue) |= $keyVpc' ${parameters.json | sponge parameters.json
```

I have to imagine that there's a better way to do this that doesn't require 5 copies of the same three lines. The keys will always be the same names, but the values will change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity, let's first define a jq helper function for modifying the key/value pairs:

```
def munge: {ParameterKey: .OutputKey, ParameterValue: .OutputValue};
```

Let's also assume that the contents of vpc.json is available as the jq variable $vpc --
 this can be accomplished (for example) as shown below.

The update can then be performed by this jq filter:

```
. + (($vpc | map(munge)) - .)
```

The following invocation is one of several possibilities but has the advantage of not requiring the most recent jq version:

```
jq -f vpc.jq --argfile vpc vpc.json parameters.json
```

#### Variations

Depending on the detailed requirements, more efficient variations might be possible.  For example, if the order of the key/value pairs is unimportant:

```
(. + ($vpc | map(munge))) | unique
```

Conversely, to avoid duplication within ($vpc|map(munge)) while preserving the ordering:

```
reduce ($vpc[] | munge) as $new
  (.; if index($new) then . else . + [$new] end)
```

Comment: Very sorry, realized I made a typo when composing my question; the values don't have their prefixes stripped. Would you mind editing if that effects your answer?

Comment: @Alex, the change should be pretty straightforward, no? Just take out the `sub()`, making `munge` that much simpler.

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know so you could edit it to match :) I'll be implementing this shortly and accepting if it works, thanks for answering!